# Serializar relación Django REST framework 3.3.1 con Django 1.8

Tags: python, django, djangorestframework

Al crear un objeto necesito obtener el siguiente response:

```
{
  "id":53,
  "cantidad":2,
  "obra":1,
  "compra":5,
  "detalle": {
    "id": 1,
    "cantidad": 15,
    "asignados": 2,
    "pendientes": 13
  }
}
```

Con los siguientes serializer obtengo lo siguiente:

```
class DetalleOrdenSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = DetalleOrden
        fields = ('id', 'cantidad', 'asignados', 'pendientes',)


class DetalleCompraSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    detalle = DetalleOrdenSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = DetalleCompra
        fields = ('id', 'cantidad', 'obra', 'compra', 'detalle',)
```

Resultado:

```
{
  "id":53,
  "cantidad":2,
  "obra":1,
  "compra":5,
  "detalle":1
}
```

Pero si utilizo los siguientes serializer para obtener el response que necesito, obtengo el siguiente error:

```
class DetalleOrdenSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = DetalleOrden
        fields = ('id', 'cantidad', 'asignados', 'pendientes',)


class DetalleCompraSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    detalle = DetalleOrdenSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = DetalleCompra
        fields = ('id', 'cantidad', 'obra', 'compra', 'detalle',)
```

Error:

```
null value in column "detalle_id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (54, 2, 5, null, 1).
```

En ambos casos este es el json que uso en el request:

```
{
  compra: "5", 
  obra: "1", 
  detalle: "1", 
  cantidad: "2"
}
```

Y estos son los modelos:

```
class DetalleOrden(models.Model):
    orden = models.ForeignKey(Orden, related_name='ordenes')
    producto = models.ForeignKey(Producto)
    cantidad = models.PositiveIntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1)])
    precio_unidad = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0)])
    total = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0)])
    asignados = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0)], default=0, editable=False)
    pendientes = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0)], default=0, editable=False)


class DetalleCompra(models.Model):
    compra = models.ForeignKey(Compra)
    obra = models.ForeignKey(Obra)
    detalle = models.ForeignKey(DetalleOrden, related_name="detalles")
    cantidad = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1)])
```

Quedo atento a sus comentarios, saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Bien lo primero que tienes que saber es que tienes que Serializar cada relación por aparte, luego agregar depth = 1 al class Meta:

```
class DetalleOrdenSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = DetalleOrden
        fields = ('id', 'cantidad', 'asignados', 'pendientes',)


class DetalleCompraSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    detalle = DetalleOrdenSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = DetalleCompra
        fields = '__all__'
        depth = 1
```

PD: Si la relación esta abajo no funciona, no sé por que, no te preocupes, así está bien, pero a mí me pasó ese caso raro

Answer (score 0):

¿Ya revisaste la documentación de DRF? [HyperlinkedModelSerializer](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#hyperlinkedmodelserializer)

Para el tipo de relaciones de herencia se representan usando este serializador. A mi me funcionó correctamente, pero es en herencia.

Acá hay más información: [Relationships & Hyperlinked APIs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/5-relationships-and-hyperlinked-apis/)

Comment: estoy tratando de usar este serializer sun la documentación de DRF [Nested relationships](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships)

Comment: Que serializador? El que te acabo de recomendar?

Comment: No, el que está en mi comentario anterior.

Comment: No te va a funcionar para relaciones foráneas, necesitas específicamente el que te recomendé.

Answer (score 0):

El serializer segun Nested relationships, no es escribible por defecto así que debes redefinir el método `.create()`, debes quitar el `read_only=true` en `DetalleOrdenSerializer`

Comment: Hola Darwin, si bien tu respuesta puede ser correcta te invito a que leas [answer] para que sepas como podrías mejorar tu respuesta, unas líneas de código de ejemplo vendrían bien con la explicación, saludos !

Answer (score -1):

En el modelo estas declarando en el `related_name='detalles'`, este es el atributo que debes de utilizar en tu serializador y no detalle, cambia detalle de tu serializar por detalles.++